# change starting form c#

Tags: c#, forms

I started creating a forms application a couple weeks ago in C#.  After going in and making some adjustments, I've added other forms and I can't seem to find an explanation of how to switch certain properties.  I would like to make a form that I created later to be the initial window to open up, then navigate from there.  I have no problem going from one form to the next, I just can't change it so that one of them is the first to load.  I used a splash screen, but that only opens it first and then goes to the second after a time interval, rather than my button_click.  I saw it the other day, but I can't remember where it is or how to access it...

Comment: You can change it in Program.cs

Comment: Thank you.  Can't believe I forgot to check there.  What a noob I am...

Comment: @Servy - when I edit my post to make it more clear for newer programmers, can you NOT edit it and revert it to its original state.  Doesn't make you cool - it makes you counter-productive.  If you could undo that, I would appreciate it, and it might be able to help people in the future...

Comment: @GeoffOverfield You edited such that it is no longer a question.  If you want to clarify your question, you can do that, but editing it such that it ceases to be a question isn't appropriate.  Additionally you should not be adding off topic meta commentary to your question.  Your question is where you ask your question, and that's it.

Comment: @Servy People come on here looking for answers, right?  If I can come back to my old posts and answer them, how is that "not appropriate".  I couldn't "answer" it because people closed it over a year ago...  That's why I changed it the way I did.

Comment: @GeoffOverfield If you want to answer your own question you can post an answer.  Editing your question into an answer isn't appropriate.  Yes, this question is indeed closed; that doesn't suddenly make it acceptable to edit the question into an answer.

Comment: @Servy - I know you can read.  I can't post it as an answer because the question was closed by people like you over a year ago.  I edited it to provide someone who may be looking for answer with an answer, as that was my only way.  Just undo your edit.  I'll remove my "off topic meta commentary"

Comment: @I know you can read.  The fact that your question is closed doesn't make it okay to replace your question with an answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128209/discussion-between-geoff-overfield-and-servy).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your application startup object (usually Program.cs) calls Application.Run with an instance of the first form to show. Change the startup window here.

For example, you can change

```
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

to

```
Application.Run(new Form2());
```

to show Form2 instead of Form1.